# Localize App.config file at runtime

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-4.0, localization

I'm working on localization my product. Now it has 3 different languages and 3 different Resource file, so i can change language at runtime.

But I have some strings to localize in App.config file, so I can't find any information how to make it work like Resource file? I need 3 different App.config on different languages and change it at runtime.

Please, help me?

Thank you!

Comment: No, that topic is about ASP.NET first, and second - the answer is "Don't use config file to localize" - and it's not the answer.

Comment: A configuration file, whether it is an app.config or web.config, is still a config file -- and as Eoin and the original answer in the duplicate also mentioned, is not appropriate -- which is the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use the config file for localizable data.

**Edit** - Just saw your comment. It's a perfectly valid answer. that's the purpose of resource files.

Put a global resource file in the application for global (non screen speicific) settings that you need to localize

Comment: The problem is that in App.config not only setting strings, but whole XML structures that uses in XAML in all application. It'll be very hard to move it...